# Should I statically link `opengl32.lib` or `glu32.lib` when deploying a dll

Tags: windows, opengl, deployment

I want my dll to be standalone. I have a function called:

`void VisualDebug();//brings up the debug Window, calls wglCreateContext on a separate thread`

Are there potential problems, such as between different version of Windows that come from statically linking to:
`opengl32.lib` or `glu32.lib` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenGL, but `opengl32.lib` and `glu32.lib` both ship with the Windows SDK and appear to be ordinary import libraries, i.e., no matter what you do you will still be using the operating system's `opengl32.dll` and `glu32.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to link against `opengl32.lib` and `glu32.lib`. These are not actual libraries, but linker symbol stubs, which tell the linker, that the executable being built needs the DLLs `opengl32.dll` and `glu32.dll` (BTW, it's highly unlikely you actually require GLU) so that the resulting PE binary contains references to those DLLs.

The DLLs themself are part of the Windows ABI and haven't changed and never will their public interface.

So it's not only safe, but the actual recommended way to link against OpenGL in Windows (exceptions where you might want to load a software rasterizer fallback on demand apply).